# three variable heatmap in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

By using `ggplot` I would like to plot a "heatmap" with three variables having the following data:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(group=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,3,3),
           variable=c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C"),
           value=c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0),
           count=sample.int(100, 18))
```

What I tried at the moment is:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = factor(value, levels = c("A","B","C"), ordered = T))) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = count), alpha = 0.85)+
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "darkslategray1", mid = "yellow", high = "turquoise4")
```

but is giving `NA` at the y axis, but there should appear the values of "variable" field with the colors of their respective "count"(field) value.

Comment: Try with `factor(variable, ..)` instead of `factor(value, ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @stefan mentioned, you want `y` to be `variable` in this line

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = factor(value,    ## old
ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = factor(variable, ## new
```

Full code

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = factor(variable, levels = c("A","B","C"), ordered = T))) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = count), alpha = 0.85)+
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "darkslategray1", mid = "yellow", high = "turquoise4")
```

[image]